Why are passive and causative passive here mixed together?

あたし、いきなりアケミさんに落とされて気絶させられたでしょう。雑です」

"I got got dropped by Akemi and made fall. It's very rough."
Why is the passive used in the second verb but not the first? Or does the causative passive apply to the first verb too?

落とす is a transitive verb, which can be turned into the passive form straightforwardly. But 気絶する ("to lose consciousness") is an intransitive verb. In this context, you have to say 気絶させられる ("to be made to lose consciousness"), not ❌️気絶される (❌️"to be lost consciousness").
